# Windows 10: How to require login on startup but NOT resume from sleep

Tags: windows-10, login, security-policy

Is it possible to have Windows 10 (Pro) require login on startup and reboot but NOT wake from sleep or power-saving screen off?

Thanks

Comment: I think if you log in as an administrator and then go to settings - accounts - sign in options - you will see a drop-down menu for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable Windows requiring sign-in on wake-up from sleep,
use the Group Policy Editor (not available in Windows 10 Home):

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
  Power Management > Sleep Settings*
- Double-click the two policies labeled
  "Require a Password when the computer wakes ..." and set them
  to Disabled
- Reboot for the policies to take effect.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. It asked for password on reboot, but not wake from sleep

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for

Settings - Account - Sign in options - Require login -

You'll have 2 options, one is after sleep, the other one says "Never"

Select Never.

Comment: If I select Never, it never asks me to log in. I want it to ask for login on cold boot, however. Just not on sleep resume.

Comment: This answer is valid. But there are indeed conditions where it will not ask for a password on startup, such as, that no password is set. Therefor +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

Either password is required each time you want to unlock screen (startup, sleep, screen saver...) or it's not required at all.