# Win 10 laptop wakes from sleep to ctrl-alt-del screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, sleep, ctrl-alt-delete

Old windows laptop (Fujitsu T732), had to upgrade from 7 to 10 against my will and better judgement. Since the upgrade, when opening the laptop from sleep it defaults to the ctrl-alt-delete screen (also called "security options" when initally loading), the one with options Lock, Switch user, Sign out, Change a password, Task Manager, and the Cancel button.

How do I make it not do this? My desired behavior is to wake directly to desktop (only one user on the device).

Other searches have yielded ways to prevent defaulting to the Lock screen, applying solutions to these do skip the lock screen on intial boot, but not when waking to the security screen. Have also tried options to not require password on wake and boot, so far to no effect.

Potentially related problem, when going to Lock or Switch User from the ctrl-alt-del screen, about 50% of the time most of the keyboard keys do not work. Fixed through a restart.

Comment: Whats your actual question

Comment: Edited text body, how do I make it skip the security screen and go directly to desktop

Comment: (1) Run `netplwiz`, Advanced tab, and ensure that "Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete" is unchecked.. (2) If your screensaver is photo gallery, try to change it to Photos. (3) Does it happen if the screensaver is None? (4) In *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters* run the Power troubleshooter.

Comment: (1) Box is unchecked.  (2,3) Screensaver was set to None, switching to Photos does not fix the issue, currently back on None setting.  (4) Running the Power Troubleshooter says it fixes some things related to efficiency, like dimming the display sooner, but the original problem persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10: How to require login on startup but NOT resume from sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/1717972/windows-10-how-to-require-login-on-startup-but-not-resume-from-sleep)

Comment: This and other options to not require login do not work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Windows Settings
2. Account
3. Sign-in option (left menu)
4. Require sign-in dropdown box -> When PC wakes up form sleep
5. Require sign-in -> Never

The next time the computer wakes from sleep mode, the computer will automatically login and not ask for
the password.

Comment: This and other options to not require logon do not work.